# User multiline input converted to an array and processed individually

Tags: c#, arrays, process, textbox, multiline

I can't find any examples nor determine how to send lines from a text box to an array and used individually as part of an argument for cmd.exe.

I can make a single line be processed but when I try to implement the array I get hung up.

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Textbox1Var = Textbox1.Text;
        string[] Textbox2Var = Textbox1.Text.Split('\n');
        void RunCmd()
        {
            Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k [command] parameter1 " + 
Textbox1Var + " " + Textbox2Var).WaitForExit();
//I know this isn't right and I probably need a foreach somewhere
//That's wht I need help with. 
//This is the current stored code but have made multiple attempts
        }
        RunCmd();
    }
```

I expect the process to be completed and responses to be displayed with the user hitting enter to close the prompt, but currently I have only gotten errors in my code or have had a loop problem...

Comment: I don't see how that's pertinent to my use case, but suppose calling cmd.exe was just to have the command box not disappear so the results can be viewed. What would you do differently? My use case was described: I expect the process to be completed and responses to be displayed with the user hitting enter to close the prompt.

Comment: The main issue was the array. I can call the command without cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all entries in the `Textbox2Var` array and print them. To do so, there is a helper function called `String.Join`.

In your code, instead of just printing `Textbox2Var`, you have to print the results of `String.Join(" ", Textbox2Var)`.

The whole line would be:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k [command] parameter1 " + Textbox1Var + " " + String.Join(" ", Textbox2Var)).WaitForExit();
```

This assumes that the arguments should be seperated by a blank whitespace.

Comment: I don't see how this creates multiple lines of [command] parameter1 " + Textbox1Var + " " + String.Join(" ", Textbox2Var)) to pass to cmd.exe based on the number of lines in textbox2

Comment: Do you want to call `Process.Start` for each line in your textbox? Maybe you should clarify your goal.

Comment: My goal is to have each line be an argument in a command that passes. Each line is a command itself. The other parameters stay whatever the user enters in other fields. They should be added to each line from the text box. Starting cmd.exe is just so that the result of the command(s) can be seen. After all commands are process the user hits enter to close the cmd.exe.

Comment: I was actually thinking, after I submitted the issue, that it might be nice to create a new array with the textbox.lines and write the lines with the other parameters appended back to the textbox for verification before processing them. Would this be easier?